# How do I provide temporary access to SFTP/phpMyAdmin on AWS Lightsail Bitnami LAMP Stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, lamp, bitnami

I want to provide temporary access to SFTP and phpMyAdmin on my AWS Lightsail Bitnami LAMP stack install.

Not sure how to do this as I have my SSH setup on my computer however if I give them all the keys then they have access to the server forever.

Any suggestions?

I don't mind reading documentation however I couldn't find how to do this.

I need to give 2 companies temporary access so they can do technical support on my site.

Thank you for your time, knowledge and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding SSH, You will want to add the user to the server, each with their own ssh key pair. Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/16650/create-a-new-ssh-user-on-ubuntu-server

When they are done with the project, then delete the users.

Regarding phpMyAdmin, you will need to create users in the mysql table and provide them access. See [Adding User Accounts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html)